# Parse.Cloud.httpRequest returning "Request failed; 35-111 SSL connect error; Connection refused"

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, paypal

I am having parse cloud code which was working fully with paypal API's. Today while making some modification I notice Parse Cloud code is throwing SSL error when try to access Paypal staging API through Parse.Cloud.httpRequest. Same code works without any issue with Paypal Production API.

```
exports.get_refresh_token = function(authorization_code)
{
  var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
    var buf = new Buffer(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID + ':' + PAYPAL_SECRET, 'utf8');   
    var basicAuthString = "Basic " + buf.toString('base64');

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:"POST",
        url: API_SERVER + "/v1/oauth2/token", 
        headers: {
                "Authorization":basicAuthString,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept-Language": "en_US"
        },
        body: 'grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=' + authorization_code
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var res = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        console.log('response: ' + httpResponse + ' res: ' + res + ' at ' + res.access_token + ' rt ' + res.refresh_token);
        return Parse.Promise.as(res);
    },
    function(httpResponse) {
        console.error("Request failed " + httpResponse.text + ' : ' + authorization_code + ' ' + API_SERVER);
        return Parse.Promise.error('Unable to get refresh token');
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I currently use the sandbox for paypal express and I have this error today : `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

Comment: Hi is there any updates? I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

PayPal updated its sandbox environment to only allow TLS 1.2 connections to improve security and prepare for future PCI compliance. You can find more information about the update on the [PayPal 2016 Merchant Security Roadmap Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US).

In this case, you will need to ask Parse to find out if their environment can support TLS 1.2 only connections. A quick search of the Parse Google Group suggests that they might not support TLS 1.2 only connections yet.

Sandbox has been changed over the last couple of days and the live production site is scheduled for later this year. Please check the microsite for the official dates.